# Impersonating with MFA enabled

Tags: amazon-cognito, impersonation, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

If our user has MFA enabled in cognito and they file a support case where we as the admin would have to 'impersonate' their account to see what is going on. How would that work? There doesn't seem to be a temporary disable of MFA in cognito right? Would we have to request that the user disable MFA on their end before we can use our endpoints to impersonate the login?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "impersonate" the user with or without MFA unless the user is willing to give you their credentials! Then you can theoretically also convince them to give you their MFA as soon as they recieve it. But all of this would really bad practice. You should look for alternative like creating a dummy account and trying to recreate the issue that a user is facing. If you could give details about what you are trying to achieve by impersonating the user, maybe we could figure out some alternatives.